# PHP check variable function?

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a function to check if my variables are valid. For example, in my script I have:

```
$flag = $_GET['page'];
```

But then I get the error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpinv\php\add.php on line 8
```

I tried writing a checkVar function:

```
function checkVar($var, $method, $defaultValue){
    if (!isset($method['$var'])) 
    {
        $var = $defaultValue;
    } else {
        $var = $method['$var'];
    }
}
```

But then I get:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpinv\php\functions.php on line 21
```

Comment: Is that the whole body of the function? It seems pointless. `$var` is not a reference and yet the function is not returning anything.

Comment: the provided code has no line 21, so the parse error probably is outsie the function

Comment: I didn't include the full source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing `'$var'` in your array uses `'$var'` as a string and not the value stored in `$var`.

This is probably what you want:

```
function checkVar($var, $method, $defaultValue){ 
    if (!isset($method[$var]))  
    { 
        $var = $defaultValue; 
    } else { 
        $var = $method[$var]; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

may be you should do something like this

```
    function checkVar($var, $method, $defaultValue){
        if (!isset($method[$var])) //instead of $method['$var']
        {
            $var = $defaultValue;
        } else {
            $var = $method[$var];
        }
        return $var;
    }
```

Comment: This and your checkVar function should be returning `$var`.

Comment: well true, makes sense. Edited !